# Keeping Android development separate from private account

Tags: android, android-pay, multiple-accounts

I am planning to publish an android app in the google play store in the near future. I am planning to charge a small amount of money through the play store, no advertisement.

My google AdSense account was locked a while ago and I am still not sure about the reason (google doesn't specify any). Because of this incident I became aware of how dependent I am on the goodwill of google.

Therefore I would like to separate my android development as much as possible from my private account.
However, of course, I don't want to violate any company policy regarding multiple accounts.

After reading around for a while I am rather certain that using a separate google account for android development is permitted (maybe somebody can confirm this, just to be sure?).

However, I am not sure about the google wallet account that is required.
I have a private wallet account that is registered with my credit card.
I only have one credit card. Am I allowed to create a new wallet account with the same credit card that I am using on my private account?

Is it going to be a problem that on my private google account my google AdSense account was disabled by google?

Is there anything I might be forgetting with my setup?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Google's official Android Developers blog indeed [recommends using a separate account](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/google-play-developer-8-step-checkup.html), and if you have already signed up with your personal account you can get the fee of registering the separate account reimbursed.

(was trying to find that post since I was about to switch my developer account myself and forgot the details, and found this post instead)

Answer (score 0):

"After reading around for a while I am rather certain that using a separate google account for android development is permitted (maybe somebody can confirm this, just to be sure?)".

Google confirms it in **[Protect your developer account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2543765)** article:

> **Use a different account for your developer account**
>
> If your developer account is linked to your personal Google Account,
>   consider creating a
>   new account to use for your developer account. This way, if one
>   account is compromised, the other account can still be secure.
>
> If you’ve already registered, our support team can transfer your apps
>   to a new account. To transfer your apps to a different account,
>   register a new developer account, then prepare and request the
>   transfer with our support team.
>
> Note: If you close your old account, we will refund your original $25
>   registration fee.